# Difference between org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost and org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.PostMethod?

Tags: java, apache, http

Hi i am trying to use httpClient for the first time and am quite confused regarding the methods under it

what is the difference between 
org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost and org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.PostMethod?

functionality wise will there be any major differences?
Also I notice the methods supported are different why is this so?

Answer (score 2):

See https://hc.apache.org/httpclient-legacy/index.html. This library is obsolete and has been replaced by https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/. Just ignore the older one.

Comment: so  org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.PostMethod is kind of upgraded version?

Comment: No, it's the obsoleted version.

Comment: So i should be using something like below ? correct me if i am wrong                                                                           HttpClient httpclient = new HttpClient();
  HttpPost post = new HttpPost();

  StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(xml);
  entity.setContentType("text/xml");
  post.setEntity(entity);                                                                 int respCode = httpclient.executeMethod((HttpMethod) post);

Comment: apache HttpClient is an excellent library. But since it provides a comprehensive solution it inevitably becomes a bit more complex. If you just need something simple (Just to send a request to a URL and to read the response (textual or binary)) you can use HttpClient class provided in MgntUtils since version 1.5.0.2. Here is the link to Maven: https://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.github.michaelgantman%7CMgntUtils%7C1.5.0.2%7Cjar and here is a link to github: https://github.com/michaelgantman/Mgnt. See the Javadoc for HttpClient class for help